# Logging on gcloud node.js

Tags: node.js, gcloud-node

I'm experimenting with node.js and managed servers. So far so good. I just can't figure out how to log to the console on my development server. I'm talking about the console I see in the terminal after running gcloud preview app run . (not the browser console). console.log() doesn't appear to do anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this command:

```
 gcloud preview app --verbosity debug run .
```